# how do i get a specific client detail from clients model,i always get the first client each time i try

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

my invoice controller looks like this

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user = current_user

    @client = @user.clients.find_by(params[:id])

  end

  def show

  end

  def create

  end

end
```

I have this on my `create_invoice` page

```
<td><%= @client.last_name %></td>
```

the link to my `create_invoice` page which is attached next to each client listed in the view looks like this

```
<td><%=link_to "Create Inv.",invoices_new_path(@client) %></td>
```

Comment: How many records are there in clients table?

Comment: just 2 records @npava

Comment: @pavan do you have an idea how to resolve the problem pls

Comment: Try replacing `@client = @user.clients.find_by(params[:id])` with `@client = Client.find_by(params[:id])`

Comment: tried it but its the same result as the first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your sql statement:

```
@user.clients.find_by(params[:id])
```

This will produce statement which looks something like (for example):

```
SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (1234124) LIMIT 1
```

And as you see it's incorrect, since condition is wrong (`WHERE (1234124)`), and returning first record to you.

If you are using `find_by` method, you should specify column you are looking for. So you should fix it to:

```
@user.clients.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

or:

```
@user.clients.find(params[:id])
```

Keep in mind that first solution will return nil if no record is found, and second one will fail loudly.

Comment: but i still have another question,how do i perform a has_many: through realationship in rails,my user has_many :clients,and clients belongs_to :user,so how do i add the invoice model,will it be user has_many :invoices through :clients and clients has_many :invoices?

Comment: DB structure depends on what are you trying to achieve. But yes, your solution should work.